# child component emit an custom event, but parent component's listener not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm registered a child component in Vue, the child will emit an custom event, but the parent component's listener not triggered.

```
<template id="add-item-template">
<div class="input-group">
  <input @keyup.enter="addItem" v-model="newItem" >
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button @click="addItem" type="button">Add!</button>
  </span>
</div>
</template>

<div id="app" class="container">
  <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
  <add-item-component v-on:itemAdd="addAItem"></add-item-component>
</div>

Vue.component('add-item-component', {
  template: '#add-item-template',
  data: function () {
    return {
        newItem: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      this.$emit('itemAdd');
      console.log("itemAdd In add-item-component");
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { 
    title: 'Welcome to Vue' 
  },
  methods: {
    addAItem: function () {
      console.log("In #app, addAItem()!");
    }
  }
});
```

The "itemAdd In add-item-component" log show in console, but "In #app, addAItem()!" log not, the #app's method addAItem not invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that custom events should not be named with camelCase.  If you look at the error message in the console, it tells you:

> Event "itemadd" is emitted in component  but the handler is registered for "itemAdd"

The component is emitting a lowercase version even though you've used camelCase to name it.  Renaming to all lowercase or kebab-case will fix it.

In the parent template:

```
<add-item-component @itemadd="addAItem">
```

Emitting from the child:

```
this.$emit('itemadd');
```

This is discussed a bit with Evan You (Vue creator) [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4044)

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your help! When I changed event name both to lowercase, it can work. Just a little problem, in my chrome's developer tool, there's no error message say the name  inconsistent, how can i see the error message?

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe your Console isn't showing the default levels of information.  Check the toolbar in the Console above the output area, to the right of the search box, there's a "levels" dropdown.  Set that to default or make sure "warnings" is checked.

Comment: There's a  "levels" dropdown above the output area and "Default" to the left of  "levels" dropdown. The two words are gray, the dropdown can not be click. I guess it is already setted to default.

Comment: Try adding this line to your `main.js`:  `Vue.config.productionTip = true`

Comment: Good. Now, there is the warning as you said: "[Vue tip]: Event "itemadd" is emitted in component <App> at src/App.vue but the handler is registered for "itemAdd". Note that HTML attributes are case-insensitive and you cannot use v-on to listen to camelCase events when using in-DOM templates..." Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah nice, you're welcome.  It seems the latest CLI's production tip is even more descriptive than jsFiddle where I tested your code too!